# Magento 2 without user login add to cart ajax not working with redis session

Tags: addtocart, ajax, redis, magento2.2.0

I have Issue with Magento version. 2.2.0 with integration of redis session.

**In my magento 2.2.0 Redis Session is enabled , Now when user is not logged in(Guest User) to the system and try to add the product to cart , its not working.**

Ajax add to cart call successfully without any error but product is not adding cart.

**Any clue for this issue**? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you check the log?

Comment: Yes. In log haven't anything related to issue.

Comment: I know this issue is in Magento 2.2.0 but can you please check same in Magento 2.2.5?